# Redirecting urls with query string

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have read several posts regarding the redirection of query strings but none of them seem to be working properly in my case.

Examples of old urls (I have several hundred with this pattern):
    http://www.example.com/cms/remository?func=fileinfo&id=1

This works, But it leaves a "?" at the target:
    redirectMatch 301 ^/cms/remository http://www.example.com/main-downloads-section?

Comment: Please specify are you using apache. `.htaccess` implies so.  and the exact rule used with flags.

Comment: Yes, Apache, version 2.2.

Comment: redirectMatch 301 ^/remository http://www.example.com/main-downloads-section? works but the result includes a "?".

Comment: I tried this earlier but it does not work: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/cms/remository$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/main-downloads-section? [R=302,L]